# I keep getting integer output for the following operation even when I am not performing floor division? I need output in float

Tags: python, numpy, integer-division

```
import numpy as np

k1=np.array([[1,-1,1,0],[0,10,25,90],[20,10,0,80]])

i=0

while(i<=2):
    
        if(k1[i,i]!=1 and k1[i,i]!=0):
              k1[i,:]=k1[i,:]/3.0
              print(k1[i,:])
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the `dtype`

```py
import numpy as np

k1=np.array([[1,-1,1,0],[0,10,25,90],[20,10,0,80]], dtype=np.float32)

i=0

while(i<=2):
    
        if(k1[i,i]!=1 and k1[i,i]!=0):
              k1[i,:]=k1[i,:]/3.0
              print(k1[i,:])
        i=i+1
```

```
[ 0.         3.3333333  8.333333  30.       ]
```